# CreateProcess C++ Doesn't Create Any Process

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I'm a newbie in c++ and trying to use debug apis, but i can't even start. Because i couldn't run any exe by CreateProcess api. It doesn't give any compile error, but does return false. Do you have any suggestions?

```
LPCWSTR appName = LPCWSTR("C:\\TEST.EXE");
LPSTARTUPINFO sInfo = LPSTARTUPINFO();
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = LPPROCESS_INFORMATION();

if (CreateProcess(appName,NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,NULL,sInfo,pInfo))
{
    printf("done!");
}
else
{
    printf("error!");
}
```

Comment: Use GetLastError() to get information about why it failed.

Comment: 87 It gives. I've searched about it and i see that its about arguments, but which one and why :)?

Comment: Yeah, "one or more parameters is incorrect" isn't too useful. Glad someone had the right answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sInfo` and `pInfo` are not pointing to valid memory (and error code `87` means *The parameter is incorrect.*). Change to:

```
STARTUPINFO sInfo = { sizeof(sInfo };
TCHAR desktop[] = TEXT("winsta0\\default");
sInfo.lpDesktop = desktop;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
```

and pass the addresses of the objects to `CreateProcess()` (i.e. `&sInfo, &pInfo`).

Comment: Thanks for the information, i did the changes but now gives error 2. Is it about file path? I'm sure that the file is there.

Comment: @halilibrahim, yep. A handy utility in Windows is "net helpmsg <code>" when gives you the description.

Comment: His appname is wrong too, casting const char* to LPCWSTR produces Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've changed CreateProcess to CreateProcessA and used LPCSTR instead of LPCWSTR. Now it works fine. But i wonder why initializing like "LPSTARTUPINFO sInfo = LPSTARTUPINFO();" doesn't work and doens't give any error?

Comment: You create a pointer to STARTUPINFO called 'sInfo' which you then initialize to be equal to another temporary pointer to STARTUPINFO.